# Access multivalued field collection tokens in webform email

Tags: 8, webforms, tokens

I tried this token `[webform_submission:source-entity:field_campaign_email_collaterals]` but this results in following html

```
field_campaign_email_collaterals 0 (Edit|Delete), 
field_campaign_email_collaterals 1 (Edit|Delete), 
field_campaign_email_collaterals 2 (Edit|Delete)
```

How can I get actuall value of this field collection, or else if there is any way to get individual field inside this field collection?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [webform_submission:node] to access field related tokens.  I think you might need to try [webform_submission:node:field_campaign_email_collaterals:0] or [webform_submission:node:field_campaign_email_collaterals:0:html]

[image: Webform node tokens]